# AJAX request firing twice while success is called once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.4, my Ajax functionality is called twice every time due to which I create two users however I want to create one user per click

actually it includes another page and that page don't have its on

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

or any function like

```
$(document).on('click','#addproject',function(){
```

but they includes script tags
but if I don't include them then Ajax is called only once
Ajax call:

```
$(document).on('click','#addproject',function(){

        $.ajax({
            type:'get',
            url:"{!! URL::to('addProject') !!}",
            data:{},
            success:function(data){
                console.log('success');
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data.length);
                $("#newproject").fadeIn();
            },
            error:function(){

            },
        });
    });
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/addProject','HomeController@addProject');
```

Controller:

```
  public function addProject(Request $request){
        $project = new Project;
        $data = array(
        );

        $project->create($data);
    }
```

Comment: Inside the click event listener put an `alert()` or `console.log()` to check if it shows two time?

Comment: yes it is called twice

Comment: Check the answer provided by me

Comment: @MayankPandeyz didn't worked

Comment: I have made few changes above, please check them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, it turns out to be I was loading this page using `load()`, but I should have loaded this page using `window.location.href = "updateform";`
Very basic mistake though.
and solution might was my app specific.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could try use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var handler = function(e){

    $.ajax({
      type:'get',
      url:"{!! URL::to('addProject') !!}",
      data:{},
      success: function(data){
        console.log('success');
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.length);
        $("#newproject").fadeIn();
        $('#addproject').one('click', handler);
      },
      error: function(){}
    });
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
}

$('#addproject').one('click', handler);
```

The one method will make sure that the handler is executed at most once per element per event type. Then after success you will need to re-bind the event handler.

Comment: but the success function is called in the last call, so I have to ignore the first one not the second one

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("#addproject").on('click',function(){
    //your code here
});
```

instead of,

```
$(document).on('click','#addproject',function(){
    //your code
});
```